# WCF служба и Entity FrameWork, проблема с конфигурацией

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, wcf

Есть WCF служба, которая  хостилась на консольном приложении.

Теперь я хочу перенести ее в WinService.

Я сделал ее библиотекой и добавил в проект WinService'а.

При запросе к WCF службе вылетает ошибка:

No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file

Что я делаю не так? Я скопировал в app.config WinService конфигурацию Консольного приложения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если меня не подводит память, то вам просто надо EntityFramework установить в сервис. Ибо он не интегрируется в DLLку. Ваш сервис стартует, читает App.config и находится в состоянии шока, ибо он не понимает данных параметров конфигурации без отдельно установленного пакета Entity Framework.

**UPDATE**

В вашем конфиге не хватает секции с конфигурацией самого Entity Framework. Точно вам не подскажу как оно должно выглядеть, но в одном из моих проектов секция выглядит следующим образом:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Теперь такая вылетает: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Comment: Добавьте в App.config конфигурацию Entity Framework'a. Почти уверен, что её в сервисе нет... Для общего понимания: после того, как вы создали библиоткеку и привязали её к другому проекту, будет использоваться конфиг и пакеты проекта к которому привязанна библиотека.

Comment: Я добавил свой конфиг в вопрос. Вот так сейчас у меня все выглядит...

Comment: Ну а я пропадейтил ответ.

Comment: Дело было в версии.  NuGet мне в конфиге прописал древнюю версию, я сменил на 6,0 и все заработало.

Comment: @iluxa1810: если делаете такие большие изменения в вопросе, то делайте их как апдейт, не искажая изначального вопроса. На ваш изначальный вопрос я дал правильный ответ, а после помены постановки вопроса мой ответ получается вообще не в попад. Этот сайт - база знаний, будьте добры и при возможности дополните вопрос изначальным описанием проблемы.

Comment: Откатил вопросю